# how to decrease the size of wordpress site after installing the wordfence

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, security, memory

Recently i had a malicious attack on my wordpress website through the EA for elementor , after that i downloaded some plugins for security and monitoring activity , like activity log for logs and wordfence . But after that my site size increased froM 15 GB to 52 GB , and i dont understand why this happened , though i was warned about wordfence , that it would take considerably large amount of resource , but i did'nt expected that much.
[image: My site Health]

i tried to optimize my website by wp-optimize , but i did'nt see much difference .

i'm using updraft plus for backup , it is taking 21 GB, i did deleted all the old backups  [image: Updraft plus]

**due to malicious activity on my website , i update the wordpress and theme and many other plugins like elementor etc.**

> is there way , i can reduce my website size , by deleting unnecessary
> files . i have hosted my site on aws server.

Comment: It's not possible to provide any help with the information provided. You must be storing a lot of data in your WordPress folder outside of the uploads, themes or plugins directory, and it's impossible to see what that is from here. You should ask your host for help.